# Function keyup executed even though its not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input called itemtitle. When I click on a button the element called counter increases by one. So the code bellow works for the first item. The counter div's innerHTML is 1 and when I write in the itemtitle input the text shows up on item 1.

```
if (document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML === "1"){  
$("#itemtitle").keyup(function() {
$("#item1").html($("#itemtitle").val());
});
```

I click the button again and the counter innerHTML goes up to 2. I there have the following code.

```
if (document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML === "2"){  
$("#itemtitle").keyup(function() {
$("#item2").html($("#itemtitle").val());
});
```

But when I write in the itemtitle input the text shows up on both item1 and item2. Even though the counter value is 2. How do I solve this? When counter is 1 I only want the text to go to item1. And when counter is 2 it should only go to item 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You register the keyup function based on the counter value. From then on it is ALWAYS active. Find out about events and event listeners in general, how that stuff works, right now you are on the wrong track about them completely.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering `keyup` event based on those two `if` conditions, So it would not mean that the particular `events` will fire only when the `if condition` matches, It would fire all the times. So what you should do is, Write a `if condition` inside that `keyup` event, so that the branching statement would react according to the `html` values. i.e] 1 or 2

Try this,

```
$("#itemtitle").keyup(function() {
   if($.trim($("#counter").html()) === "1")
     {
       $("#item1").html($(this).val());
     }
   else
     {
       $("#item2").html($(this).val());
     }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that they need to be seperated. So I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now. And were still able to have them seperated. I changed it to:

```
$("#itemtitle").keyup(function() {
if (document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML === "1"){
$("#item1").html($("#itemtitle").val());
}
});
```

This way it checks the value whenever i enter something into the input.